# Rewriting a double summation.

Tags: summation

If I am given this function: $$f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^x}$$
Is there a way to rewrite:
$$g(x) = \sum_{ j = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{i = j}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i \cdot j)^x}$$
In terms of f(x). By simple arthimatic I know that $f(x)^2 = 2 \cdot g(x) - f(2x)$.
The question is if for a more general way to rewrite the summation. If $g(x)$ contained 3 summation with $i,j,k$ how would you rewrite it in terms of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_1(x) &=&  \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{i^x} \\ 
f_2(x) &=& \sum_{i >j \geq 1} \frac{1}{(ij) ^x} \\ 
f_3(x) &=& \sum_{i>j>k \geq 1} \frac{1}{(ijk)^x}. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
In your question you have calculated
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2^x} + \frac{1}{3^x} + \cdots \right) ^2 &=& \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{i^{2x} } + 2 \sum_{i >j \geq 1} \frac{1}{(ij) ^x} \\
(f_1(x))^2 &=& f_1(2x) +2 f_2(x).
\end{eqnarray*}
Calculating similarly 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2^x} + \frac{1}{3^x} + \cdots \right) ^3 = \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{i^{3x} } + 3 \sum_{i >j \geq 1} \frac{1}{(i^2j) ^x} + 3 \sum_{i >j \geq 1} \frac{1}{(ij^2) ^x} + 6 \sum_{i >j>k \geq 1} \frac{1}{(ijk) ^x} \\
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2^x} + \frac{1}{3^x} + \cdots \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2^{2x}} + \frac{1}{3^{2x}} + \cdots \right) = \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{i^{3x} } +  \sum_{i >j \geq 1} \frac{1}{(i^2j) ^x} +  \sum_{i >j \geq 1} \frac{1}{(ij^2) ^x} .  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply the second equation by $3$ and subtract it from the first gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
(f_1(x))^3  -3f_1(x) f_1(2x) = -2f_1(3x) +6 f_3(x).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: In the line right after "Calculating similarily" shouldn't it be $\sum_{i>1} \frac{1}{i^{3x}}$

Comment: Yes, well spotted ... Thank  you.

Comment: I went through the math and I think the final answer is $(f_1(x))^3 + 3f_1(x)f_2(2x) = $...

Comment: There is a little subltety ... is the sum $i \color{red}{>} j \geq 1 $ or $i \color{red}{ \geq} j \geq 1 $ ... In my answer I use the former & in your question you use the latter ... this will account for the minus sign. Either way the calculation
will very similar.

Answer (score 0):

For
$g(x) 
= \sum_{ j = i}^{\infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(i \cdot j)^x}
$
and sums like it,
anything independent
of the innermost index of summation
can be pulled out.

However,
you have a mistake in
the way you have written this:
An outer summation
can not depend
on more inner indices.

This should be written
$g(x) 
= \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{ j = i}^{\infty}  \dfrac{1}{(i \cdot j)^x}
$.

Also note that
$i$ must start at $1$
since
$\dfrac1{i^x}$
is not defined at $i = 0$.

In this case,
you can do
$g(x) 
=  \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{ j = i}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(i \cdot j)^x}
=  \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{i^x}\sum_{ j = i}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{j^x}
$.

You can also reverse the order of summation
to get
$g(x) 
=  \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{ j = i}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(i \cdot j)^x}
=  \sum_{ j = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{i = 1}^{j} \dfrac{1}{(i \cdot j)^x}
=  \sum_{ j = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{j^x}\sum_{i = 1}^{j} \dfrac{1}{i^x}
$.

Comment: Yeah you're right the order was mixed up. Let me edit the question, because I think the sum I wanted is not the one you showed.